# Failover of mirrored webservice

Tags: failover

We are using a webservice (over http) which has 2 mirrored servers, accessible as, say www.blah.com and www2.blah.com. Is there a software solution that would help us handle failover? Currently if one server becomes unavailable, I need to manually edit our config to point at the other server. Failover on their side is "in the works", so I don't want to do checking for server availability in code. On our side, we use a mix of linux and windows boxes, so we have both os's in the cage.

Answer (score 0):

We use [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) to do load balancing and it works extremely well.

Comment: Good call, but obviously this requires an extra box (or two). If you used a simple heartbeat service and a VIP you could just keep the setup down to two boxes.

Comment: Not necessarily, depending on load you could run HAproxy on both your web servers in this instance.